# Connecting UITableView to UIView error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

sorry if the question is a beginners one its because I am a beginner.

I have a nib file that called `HistoryLogTableViewController`. in this nib file I have a UIView and a UITableView, the UIView is the parent of the UITableView.

`HistoryLogTableViewController` screenshot:

[image]

This nib file have a view controller called `HistoryLogTableViewController` that have a table view property in the .h file that is connected to the files owner, it looks like this:

[image]

and this is the property in the .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

now from what I knew if I run the app now it should work...just load an empty table view...but when I click on the button that opens this table view the app crashes and I get this error:

`reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "HistoryLogTableViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.`'

Comment: `IBOutlet` should be `weak`.

Comment: Well, can you please change the `HistoryLogTableViewController` inherited class to UIViewController from UITableViewController? Look into `HistoryLogTableViewController.h` the interface should be `HistoryLogTableViewController : UIViewController`.

Comment: Yep, you have property defined wrong,just control-drag from Nib to your .h file and it creates outlet for you

Comment: @Yanchi this is what I did..

Comment: @Larme I know, but when I do this I get a warning: 'retain (or strong)' attribute on property 'tableView' does not match the property inherited from 'UITableViewController''

Comment: Nick, (strong, nonatomic) not what gets generated when you ctrl-drag... (weak, nonatomic) should be generated... But I hold on until you try Warren's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im guessing your class looks like this

`@interface HistoryLogTableViewController : UITableViewController`

A `UITableViewController` MUST have a `UITableView` as the root view of the controller not a `UIView`.

change it to this

`@interface HistoryLogTableViewController : UIViewController`

and it should stop crashing.